# Problems generating Eclipse CDT project from CMake

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

If I create a C++ project with Eclipse (Simple Hello World - Project), in the Project Explorer if I do right click -> Properties, I can see a section C/C++ Build in which I can choose, under the Combobox Configuration, Release, Debug, etc..

But, If I create an Eclipse project with CMake using:

`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm.cmake -DPROJECT=example_01 -DVERSION=1.0.0.0 -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ..`

(ignore the params before -G "Eclipse...", I need them to compile), when I import it doing File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace, if I do right click as described above, the section C/C++ Build is missing.

- Is there a way to make it visible?
- Is there a way to add other options in that configuration combobox from the CMake (like FLAGS, or particular commands)?

Comment: Try to import using File->Import->C/C++/Existing code as makefile project. Doing this way I was able to access C/C++ build menu under Project properties

Comment: Can you inspect the generated `.project` file? Does it have the expected `<nature>` elements?

Comment: @Botje Inside the .project there is 

<natures>
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.make.core.makeNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.make.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
</natures>

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, If you do what you said, Eclipse shows you the build menu. But, do you know if there is a way to add from CMake other options in the configuration combobox in the build menu?